# What are the best practices for structuring a FastAPI project?

Tags: python, fastapi

The problem that I want to solve related the project setup:

- Good names of directories so that their purpose is clear.
- Keeping all project files (including virtualenv) in one place, so I
  can easily copy, move, archive, remove the whole project, or estimate disk
  space usage.
- Creating multiple copies of some selected file sets such as entire
  application, repository, or virtualenv, while keeping a single copy of
  other files that I don't want to clone.
- Deploying the right set of files to the server simply by resyncing
  selected one dir.
- handling both frontend and backend nicely.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/ycd/manage-fastapi

Comment: 66 upvotes and someone closed this question, wow

Comment: This is a GREAT question. What more focused do you need it to be?!

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Harsha already mentioned my [project generator](https://github.com/ycd/manage-fastapi) but I think it can be helpful for future readers to explain the ideas behind of it.

If you are going to serve your frontend something like **yarn** or **npm**. You should not worry about the structure between them. With something like **axios** or the Javascript's **fetch** you can easily talk with your backend from anywhere.

When it comes to structuring the backend, if you want to render templates with Jinja, you can have something that is close to MVC Pattern.

```py
your_project
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── core
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── database.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── schemas
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── schema.py
│   └── settings.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── v1
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_v1.py
└── v1
    ├── api.py
    ├── endpoints
    │   ├── endpoint.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── __init__.py
```

By using `__init__` everywhere, we can access the variables from the all over the app, just like Django.

Let's the folders into parts:

- **Core**

  - **models**

    - **database.py**
  - **schemas**

    - **users.py**
    - **something.py**
  - **settings.py**
  - **views** *(Add this if you are going to render templates)*

    - **v1_views.py**
    - **v2_views.py**
- **tests**
- **v1**
- **v2**

#### Models

It is for your database models, by doing this you can import the same database session or object from v1 and v2.

#### Schemas

Schemas are your Pydantic models, we call it schemas because it is actually used for creating OpenAPI schemas since FastAPI is based on OpenAPI specification we use schemas everywhere, from Swagger generation to endpoint's expected request body.

#### settings.py

It is for [Pydantic's Settings Management](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/settings/) which is extremely useful, you can use the same variables without redeclaring it, to see how it could be useful for you check out our documentation for [Settings and Environment Variables](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/)

#### Views

This is optional if you are going to render your frontend with Jinja, you can have something close to MVC pattern

- **Core**

  - **views**

    - **v1_views.py**
    - **v2_views.py**

It would look something like this if you want to add views.

#### Tests

It is good to have your tests inside your backend folder.

#### APIs

Create them independently by APIRouter, instead of gathering all your APIs inside one file.

#### Notes

You can use absolute import for all your importing since we are using `__init__` everywhere, see [Python's packaging](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) docs.

So assume you are trying to import **v1's endpoint.py** from **v2**, you can simply do

```py
from my_project.v1.endpoints.endpoint import something
```

Comment: question : how do you version core ? Let's say you need to change your pydantic model from v1 to v2

Comment: where i add migrations folder when using alembic?

Comment: Why is it good to have the tests in the backend folder? AFAIK separation of tests and business logic is preferable?

Answer (score 19):

The official documentation suggests the below style like Flask blueprints.

```
.
├── app                  # "app" is a Python package
│   ├── __init__.py      # this file makes "app" a "Python package"
│   ├── main.py          # "main" module, e.g. import app.main
│   ├── dependencies.py  # "dependencies" module, e.g. import app.dependencies
│   └── routers          # "routers" is a "Python subpackage"
│   │   ├── __init__.py  # makes "routers" a "Python subpackage"
│   │   ├── items.py     # "items" submodule, e.g. import app.routers.items
│   │   └── users.py     # "users" submodule, e.g. import app.routers.users
│   └── internal         # "internal" is a "Python subpackage"
│       ├── __init__.py  # makes "internal" a "Python subpackage"
│       └── admin.py     # "admin" submodule, e.g. import app.internal.admin
```

Taken from the official link, read more at https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/